# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' - HTTPS Error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I see the following error when getting data from Firebase for my iOS app:

*2018-01-06 14:55:09.327043-0500 Spirit-App[65852:5935746] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'URL must be in the form of http[s]://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b//o/[?token=signed_url_params]'*

I suspected this may have something to do with Info.plist so as a workaround I attempted to modify the App Transport Security Settings but the same message still appears. Is there another location, besides Info.plist, that would need changed? Or is there a specific location where I can edit the firebase URL referenced above to correct the issue? Thanks!

Comment: How does your request url looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using one of the internal reference functions of Firebase which converts a URL to a storage reference. For e.g. the code below

```
let httpsReference = storage.reference(forURL: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/b/bucket/o/images%20stars.jpg")
```

In such an instance, the above exception is thrown if the URL is not in the correct format as explained in the error message. You will need to check that the URL has the valid prefix in the string before passing it to the `reference` function.

I am trying to answer your question without having a view of your source code where the error is occurring. So if you want more details, please post the source code and I will update my answer.